# Snow creates circles on my photos, how do I prevent that?

Tags: photography-basics, snow

When I take photographs outdoors during snowfall, the snow flakes creates circles in the picture and end up blurring what I was actually trying to photograph. I'm a beginner, am I completely oblivious to something?

Comment: Do you have an example of this? What camera setup are you using? Is the flash on?

Comment: Are you using the flash?

Comment: Tonia: please edit your question to include an example of the issue you're having. I've upvoted this question so you should (soon) have enough reputation to do this - but note I've also voted to close it as unclear in its current form. I'll retract that close vote if an example is added.

Comment: All it takes, in big fluffy snow, is for one foreground fluffball (you can't really call them "flakes" anymore at that scale) to be between subject and lens at the instant of taking. In the right spot, it's "winter wonderland" time; in the wrong spot, it's bokeh censorship. Slower shutter speed or shoot a bunch and pick a good one are the only ways around that.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen as shown [here](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/q/4628/13451), a 1 rep unregistered user can post a question with an image.

Answer (score 0):

If you're shooting snow at night with a flash, and the circles you're talking about are large, white, and fuzzy, what you're seeing are "[orbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orb_%28optics%29)"--out of focus reflections of the on-camera flash burst from particulate matter in the air--like snow. This can also happen with rain and dust.

The only way to avoid it is to a) not use the flash, or b) adjust the angle of the flash (or use a flash off-camera) in such a way that these reflections don't came straight back to the camera lens. With a point and shoot camera, this can be difficult, since the flash is so close to the lens, and you probably don't have an external hotshoe or other way to trigger a remote flash.